# problem with displaying data, coming from sqlite in laravel views?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with mysqlite database and laravel for practice purpose. I create a model with php artisan make:model Channel --fmc command, Then I include name field in migration file and run php artisan migrate. By using php artisan tinker, I populate the database/database.sqlite file. By running 
App\Channel::all() on tinker, it shows all records. But problem is that when i try to get all records in my ChannelController.php it shows error. where is the problem in my code.

ChannelController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Channel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ChannelController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
       $channels = Channel::all();

       dd($channels->name);

       return view('channel.index',compact($channels));
    }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('channels','ChannelController@index');
```

ChannelFactroy.php

```
use App\Channel;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Channel::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->word,
    ];
});
```

Error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 (SQL: select * from `channels`)
```

and

```
   catch (Exception $e) {

            throw new QueryException(

                $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e

            );

        }
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad, you are getting this error because mysql is trying to tell you that there is no server running. Try to restart your server.

Comment: I think you get this error because there is a firewall blocking the connection or the process that is hosting the service is not listening on that port. Check your running port list.